# Regular expression that matches "{$" AND NOT matches "\{$"

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a project with lexical analysis and basically I have to generate tokens that are **text** and that are **not text**.

- Tokens that are **text** are considered all characters until the `"{$"` sequence.

  Tokens that are **not text** are considered all characters inside the `"{$"` and `"$}"` sequences.

Note that the `"{$"` character sequence can be *escaped* by writing `"\{$"` so this also becomes a part of **text**.
My job is to read a *String* of **text**, and for that I am using *Regular expressions*.

I am using the Java [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) classes and this is my work so far:

```
String text = "This is \\{$ just text$}\nThis is {$not_text$}."
Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
Pattern textPattern = Pattern.compile("{\\$"); // insert working regex here
sc.useDelimiter(textPattern);

System.out.println(sc.next());
```

This is what should be printed out:

> This is \{$ just text$}
>     This is

How do I make a *regex* for the following logical statement:

> **match** "{$" **AND NOT match** "\{$"

Comment: My best recommendation for trying out regex is to use a tool like: https://regex101.com/ . You will still have to tweak it a tiny bit to make sure it's 100% java compatible. It will help get you there however.

Comment: Do you have to provide delimiter to Scanner, or can you first read entire string (even with scanner) and later parse it (even with regex)?

Comment: It would be a good thing to have `Scanner` delimiter because after it returns the first token, the next one is sure to be a non-text token (or end of string) and I want it to continue from where it left off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [*Negative Look-Behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\\)` in front of `\{\$` to ensure that escaped curly braces are not matched:

```
(?<!\\)\{\$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE2bV0/1)

Comment: One trap with this approach is having escaped ``\`` before `{$`. I mean when ``\`` is literal, not escaping char. This would prevent having proper `{$` from representing non-text sequence.

Comment: A way of handling the general case (as indicated by @Pshemo) would be more interesting. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
String text = "This is \\{$ just text$}\nThis is {$not_text$}.";
Pattern textPattern = Pattern.compile(
          "(?<text>(?:\\\\.|(?!\\{\\$).)+)" // text - `\x` or non-start-of `{$`
        + "|"                        // OR
        + "(?<nonText>\\{\\$.*?\\$\\})");      // non-text
Matcher m = textPattern.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1)!=null){
        System.out.println("text : "+m.group("text"));
    }else{
        System.out.println("non-text : "+m.group("nonText"));
    }
}
System.out.println("\01234");
```

Explanation:

From what I see, you want `\` to be *special character* used for escaping.
Problem now is to determine where `\` is meant to escape character/sequence after it, and when it should be treated as simple printable character (literal).

(possible problem)
Lets say that you have text `dir1\dir2\` and you want to add after it non-text `foo`. How would you write it?

You could try writing `dir1\dir2\{$foo$}` but this could mean that you just escaped `{$` which would prevent `foo` from being seen as non-text.

In Java, String literals faced same problem since `\` can be used to create other special characters using

- pairs `\n` `\r` `\t` `\"`
- Unicode codepoints `\uFFFF`
- octal format `\012`.

Solution used in Java (and many other languages) was making `\` always special character which to create `\` literal required escaping it with another `\` (there was no real need to add yet another special character for that). So to represent `\` we need to write it as `\\`.

So if we have text `dir1\dir2\` we would need to write it as `dir1\\dir2\\`. This would allow us to concatenate to it `{$non-text$}` without fear that this last `\\` placed right before `{$` will be causing misinterpretation of it and prevent seeing it as non-text sequence.

So now when we see `dir1\\dir2\\{$foo$}` we can interpret `{$` properly.

***From this point I am assuming you are also using this approach which ensures proper interpretation of `\`.***

Now, lets try to create rule which will let us find/separate text and non-text characters.

Based on our example we know that `dir1\\dir2\\{$foo$}` is: text `dir1\\dir2\\` and non-text `{$foo$}`.
So as you see splitting on `{$` which is not preceded by `\` can fail you sometimes (if number of preceding `\` is not odd).

Probably simpler solution is to accept

- for text:

  - `\\.` - regex representing characters which are preceded by `\` (this will handle `\\` literal and escaped `\{` (which will also allow us to accept rest of `$..$}` part)
  - `(?!\{\$).` - regex representing character which isn't `{` which would start `{$` area.
- for non-text:

  - `\{\$.*?\$\}` - regex representing `{$...$}` - we know that it will be unescaped because all escaped characters will be accepted by `\\.`.